1969s-1970s novel, mankind needs to emigrate to escape Sun going nova, women are higher status than men, men have artificial snake familiars
I think the author might have been James Blish, but scanning his bibliography didn't make it jump out. The planet they are escaping from is not, it turns out, Earth. Thanks to perfect paternity tests and safety from STDs -- two social changes posited by Arthur C. Clarke in Childhood's End -- most families started with a boy. The result is that in this society, women have more social status than men, they get all the cream of society -- higher education, better jobs, etc., etc. The other major difference to our society is the existence of an artificial snakelike animal that most men acquire and call a "familiar".
The early part of the book covers the protagonist getting a job with the organization directing the spaceship builds and overall escape effort.
The leader of the expedition, surprisingly a man, has a truly enormous familiar that he habitually carries on his shoulders, under his shirt, distorting his apparent frame to the point that people think he's deformed. I remember a shrugging gesture he made at a couple points, which it is implied was the familiar moving.
The FTL spaceships are more like overloaded life rafts than generation ships. There's no concept of the voyage lasting longer than one lifetime. After takeoff, through their FTL magic, they get to view the nova from their spaceship which is a couple light years away at the time of the nova.
They land on a few planets throughout the rest of the book. (This could possibly be a fixup novel, now that I think about it). None are suitable until the end. One planet, all the vegetation is highly acidic and produces burns when you try to eat it. Another planet, life seems to have taken many diverging paths on the question of how to maintain a solid form -- the panther-like predators have pressurized gas for bones, the insects have metal chitin, etc. (The metal insects end up being captured with magnetic fences and eventually used in a cyclotron-like affair to kill an approaching monster).  There might have been a third failed colonization, I am not positive.
The end colonization ends up being on our Earth, in prehistoric times. The implication is that humanity descends at least partly from them.

And All the Stars a Stage by James Blish from 1971, originally published in parts over several issues of Amazing Stories.
From Goodreads reviews:

A SF story of futuristic earth that has become overpopulated with males and the sun is about to explode, so mankind has to take to the stars in a hurry to find a new planet to colonize. The premise sounds interesting, with added in gender issues a SF creatures called familiars you would think this book would be good.

(The reviewers tend to think it wasn't good)

Decent old-style sci-fi. It jumped around a bit, and I think the author wasted a lot of potential when it came to the 'familiars'. I enjoyed the various Possible Habitable Planet scenarios that the exploring ships went through, though the various failures were heartbreaking.


... The ending definitely caught me by surprise in that they clearly ended up on Earth in the past.

(Even that reviewer gave it two stars despite calling it decent)
And from a SFGateway review, some more details about the premise:

There are too many men in a world governed by women. They’re bored and disillusioned and often resort to ‘suicide missions’ – jobs in experimental space research. Jorn applies for such a job, is selected and trained as a navigator for the huge ship Javelin, the first to implement the recently discovered faster-than-light Evrak Effect.


Before the Effect is tested, however, it is discovered that life will be extinct within nine years; the sun is burning up, preparing to explode. The Evrak Effect will save a small percentage of mankind, take civilisation to a yet unknown planet. Production on new ships is given priority, the ruthless selection of passengers begins. Twenty-five billion people will be left behind.

Readable with account on the Internet Archive.

The reviewers were right, and I generally like Blish's work.

Blish wrote many excellent stories, but he also wrote some real clunkers, especially when he couldn't restrain himself from preaching on moral / religious themes.

There's so much going on in this story--the supernova, the gender-dominance inversion, the... snake-familiars?--that I'm reminded of a latter-day episode of Mystery Science Theater 3000 in which the movie they were watching was so chock-full of disparate sci-fi concepts that they did a sketch in which a huckster did a song-and-dance routine called "Concepts!" in which he scammed the local rubes into buying a bunch of concepts that they didn't need, like the marching band instruments in The Music Man.  It also kind of sounds like this started out as three or more separate stories.
